# HP t410 smart zero thin client RDP Client error Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, rdp, thin-client

I'm having an issue with 2 of my HP Smart Zero t410 thin clients. They each RDP into an XP SP3 virtual machine hosted on a virtual server running VWWare ESXi 5.0.0. Randomnly in the morning they'll both disconnect from their virtual machines. Sometimes at the same time, sometimes not.

I'm monitoring both the thin clients and the virtual machines with software that pings everything 30 seconds, nothing ever drops a ping. I've tested the wire, the wire is good. I've made sure the thin clients are up to date with the latest firmware. The last thing I've tried is replacing the switch both of these machines are connection.

One thin client comes up with an error message "RDP Client Error: Reboot Necessary" then below "The firmware has experienced a critical error. Please reboot this client." After I close the error I can RDP back in.

The other thin client also gives an "RDP Client Error" and down below mentions MANTICORE but I did not write down the entire error message.

I have 30 other t410's deployed at various locations, all connected via RDP to a Windows Server 2008 R2 terminal with no issue for over a year. These last two have maybe in for three weeks and have continously thrown this error randomnly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you updated the rdp client on those thinclient ?

Comment: Possible bad ram in the affected thin clients, or corrupted firmware. Reflash them, if still getting errors, swap ram

Comment: @yagmoth555 Have you ever done so with those thin clients?

Comment: @Dan Have you run into this issue before? Did that fix your issue?

Comment: @WinskiTech Not those, but yes for multiple thin client model. Update them and if problem continue, do like Dan suggested and swap them, if problem follow the thinclient then replace it. (http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5234196&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4116)

Comment: Thin client is a less powerfull computer, but still a computer (usually a pc architecture with bios and all, but with some low power cpu). Usual issues like bad ram, corrupted flash do apply. I only have two of which I use only one, so no troubles here. Both have pc bios, can run linux or windows xp. One has modular laptop ram. Both use ide flash disks and can take laptop hdd's (except no space inside). So, as pc as it gets.

Comment: Thanks to both yagmoth555 and Dan , I'll try both of your suggestions.

Comment: @yagmoth555 and Dan I've re-created the VM on a new virtual server, I've replaced the thin client, the small desktop switch they have on site, the wire between the switch and the thin client...and I'm still running into this issue. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution, I had to bounce the thin clients through the terminal server THEN to the XP VM. Something between the Thin Client RDP client and the XP client didn't play nice when we stressed the XP VM

Comment: Is this resolved? You have not marked it as such. If you consider the question solved, tick the tick mark so that it turns solid green.